# How to show the dynamic table with dropdown in angular and how to push each row to another div

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Here I am getting below as dynamic data

```
[
    { 
        id: 151, 
        name: 'Alan B. Shepard, Jr.', 
        job: 'Astronaut', 
        year_joined: 1959,
        missions: ['MR-3', 'Apollo 14']
    },
    { 
        id: 152, 
        name: 'Virgil I. Grissom', 
        job: 'Astronaut', 
        year_joined: 1959,
        missions: ['MR-4', 'Apollo 1']
    },
    { 
        id: 153, 
        name: 'John H. Glenn, Jr.', 
        job: 'Astronaut', 
        year_joined: 1959,
        missions: ['MA-6','STS-95']
    },
    { 
        id: 154, 
        name: 'M. Scott Carpenter', 
        job: 'Astronaut', 
        year_joined: 1959,
        missions: ['MA-7']
    }
];
```

And here I can display this dynamic data in table using **angular 2** `*ngFor` but here the problem I'm facing is :

1. How to display the Dropdowns in the dynamic table here in my dynamic data I want to display "missions" field as dropdown so that user can select the dropdown.
2. Presently I am displaying the above dynamic table in divOne .How can I push it to the divTwo I mean another Div which is empty here I want to select the row or which ever row i select i want to send it to the empty div how can perform these actions

Below is my html code :

```
<table class="table" *ngFor=let data of Table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>job</th>
            <th>year_joined</th>
            <th>missions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.job}}</td>
            <td>{{data.year_joined}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Above is my code, here I dynamically getting data except "missions" I don't know how to show dropdown in dynamic table i mean in each row and how to select each row & select all of them and push it to another div

Comment: can you add html code?

Comment: @RahulSharma please check the updated one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate on the `Table` array and can build your first table. `*ngFor` structural directive should be on the `<tr>` instead of the table.

Also I have attached a click handler, this will get fired once you will click on the `tr`.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
            <th>Year Joined</th>
            <th>Mission</th>
    </thead>

    <tr *ngFor="let data of Table;let i = index" (click)=addToAnotherTable(i)>

        <td>
            <span>{{data.name}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{data.job}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{data.year_joined}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
             <option *ngFor="let mission of data.missions">
                {{mission}}
             </option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you must be seeing your table now. When you will click on any row, `addToAnotherTable(i)` will get fired, which will push the index of the clicked row in some array.

```
addToAnotherTable(ind){
  this.secondaryTable.push(ind);
}
```

Now this array will be the array we will be using to build another table.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let data of secondaryTable">
        <td>
            <span>{{Table[data].name}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{Table[data].job}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{Table[data].year_joined}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option *ngFor="let mission of Table[data].missions">
             {{mission}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

will make another table. As it is looping over the values of `secondaryTable`.

You might want to modify the functionality of `addToAnotherTable` based on your need. Like if you want to toggle the rows in table 2 on click of row in table 1 then you might use this function

```
addToAnotherTable(ind) {
    var index = this.secondaryTable.indexOf(ind);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.secondaryTable.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else{
      this.secondaryTable.push(ind);
    }
  }
```

or you might want to add sorting on the data and so on...

**See this live on stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2m94j

Comment: This is great, thank you. When a row in the Table is clicked, it is added to or removed from the secondary table using the values of the Table row, with mission being the first element of the missions. If user selects a separate mission from the dropdown for a row, how can that new mission be detected and shown in the secondary table?

Answer (score 4):

You can try similar to this.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Year Joined</th>
        <th>Mission</th>
</thead>

<tr *ngFor="let data of Table;let i = index">

    <td>
        <span>{{data.name}}</span>
    </td>
<td>
        <span>{{data.job}}</span>
    </td>

<td>
        <span>{{data.year}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
  <option *ngFor="let mission of data.mission" 
   [selected]="mission.name == 'back'">{{mission.name}}</option>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9tmzs)

Comment: ok but how can i push the selected rows & select all rows to the empty div on button click

Comment: if i understand correctly.The selected of dropdown can be binded to your model

Comment: for dropdown ok but i am saying about whole table row how can i select 1 or more table rows and push to the empty div and display these items as table in that div

Comment: I dont understand ur comment well, could u pls elaborate

Comment: @Eldho See my answer.. This is what he is trying to achieve.. See the stackblitz link.

Answer (score 2):

> Have a look at the running code below

[Stack Blitz, Source](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-show-the-dynamic-table-with-dropdown-in-angular)

[Demo](https://how-to-show-the-dynamic-table-with-dropdown-in-angular.stackblitz.io)

> I have taken your data and displayed it as a table. Here you can

1. Click to transfer rows from one table to the other
2. And be able to select from drop down as well

Answer (score 1):

Just make an call to your backend that return all missions:

`['MA-7', 'MA-6','STS-95', 'Apollo 1', 'MR-4']`

Then in the html you can make a dropdown with:

`<option *ngFor="let mission of missions"`

Comment: for dropdown ok but i am saying about whole table row how can i select 1 or more table rows and push to the empty div and display these items as table in that div

Answer (score 1):

The coding for the above scenario will take some time so I will explain you the procedure you have to follow:

1. Create another column in your first table to provide a `checkbox` for selecting each row or multiple rows and bind the `value` of checkbox to the `id` property in your data.
2. Create a button and on `click` event, call a method to get the ids of the selected rows from the checkbox values.
3. Using the ids you have got, use the `splice` method on the array to remove the data from the array and add these data(s) to another array. Any further additions can be made to the array using the `push` method.
4. Create a table just like the one you have in the `div` two also.
5. Use `*ngIf` on the second array to show or hide the table according to the length of the second array.
6. Whenever an addition is made to the second array, you second div will render it as a new row and similarly since you are using the `splice` method on the first array, the respective rows will be removed from the first table.

Please do try this method out and if you face any issues, create a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) code so that I may help you further.

I have created a sample application based on your scenario. Check out [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2iklg). I have forked you code and edited it.

Comment: I have created a sample application and edited my answer. You can find the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) is made exactly for your case. Try it out. In this example you can **select/deselect multiple missions per element**, and show it to the user without using an extra input.

The advantage of doing this way is that you will **have an easier time styling your dropdown**.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" *ngFor="let data of Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>job</th>
            <th>year_joined</th>
            <th>missions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.job}}</td>
            <td>{{data.year_joined}}</td>
            <td>
              <ng-template ngFor let-mission [ngForOf]="data.missions">
                <p class="mission"
                   [ngClass]="{'selected': data.selectedMissions.indexOf(mission) != -1}"
                   (click)="selectMission(data, mission)">
                  {{mission}}
                </p>
              </ng-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
private selectMission(data, mission):void {
  if (!data.selectedMissions)
    data.selectedMissions = new Array();

  if (data.selectedMissions.indexOf(mission) == -1)
    data.selectedMissions.push(mission);
  else
    data.selectedMissions.slice(data.selectedMissions.indexOf(mission));

  console.log(data.selectedMissions);
}
```

**CSS**

```
p.mission.selected {
  background-color:#F0F;
}
```

**Didn't try but it should work. If you want to make something cleaner you can write a new data instead of modifying the current one, and play with the prototypes of your objects.**

You will find out how to style your page in order to [make a dropdown here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)